# Deploying jwebsocket server (20614) in tomcat (or tomee)

Tags: websocket, apache-tomee

I have followed the instructions to run the demo provided. I also tried to create a simple plugin to see if I can get it to work. I am running into a problem where the factory cannot instantiate the Plugins, be it one I created or any of the other (e.g. AdminPlugin).

The exception indicates that the constructor that takes org.jwebsocket.api.PluginConfiguration as param is missing.

Has anybody else run into this problem?
Is the 20614 version broken?
Is the versions packaged incorrectly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I have abandoned jwebsocket due to:<br/>
+Unresponsiveness on jwebsocket forum as well as emails
+ Project packaging seems to be in disarray
+ Unreliable versioning

Just a heads up if you plan to use the jwebsockets.

I ended up using Tomcat's websocket implementation with weberknecht as client. A bit worries about weberknecht and the different versions/implementations out there.